# Change keyboard options in Plasma Wayland

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, wayland

Currently, I'm using `altwin:swap_lalt_lwin,ctrl:swapcaps` options on my keyboard layout. Sometimes I would like to disable them using a shortcut, but I don't know how. So far, I know that file `~/.config/kxkbrc` changes each time the keyboard options are modified in the Settings (Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advance).

**Is there a way to disable or change the keyboard options using a shortcut in KDE?**

In X11, the `setxkbmap` command works and I think it's possible to add a shortcut that toggles the options on and off. I haven't yet found an equivalent command for `kwin` or Wayland in general.

Version:
kwin 5.27.7

Comment: system settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts ?